# GPGS: Unexpected response code: 500 when loading data

Tags: connection, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using google play game services to set up the multiplayer for a game that I am developing but am having some issues testing it on two devices. On the device with my account, everything works fine. On my test device with a test account, I get the "java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code: 500" error. Here is the full error:

```
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817): Error downloading: EntrySpec[43]
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817): java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code: 500
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata.sync.syncadapter.a.f.a(SourceFile:232)
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata.sync.syncadapter.a.f.a(SourceFile:69)
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata.sync.syncadapter.a.g.run(SourceFile:344)
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-15 15:13:37.688: E/FileDownloader(817):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Since saving and loading works fine on my device, I figured that the issue must be with the way I configured the app in the Google console. I have the test email added under testing (Developer Console -> Game Services -> Click on app (says ready to be tested) -> Go to testing -> add email) and I don't think there is anything else that needs to be configured. The user with the test email can login but cannot save and load.

I am not sure what the problem is or how to debug this issue further. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but does the test account have Drive access (i.e. have you logged into Drive with that account at least once)?

Comment: I have logged into google drive with the test account, so I assume it does have access.

Comment: I created a new test account and it seems to be working fine, but I still feel like I need to know what caused the other test account to not upload and retrieve data.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. There is some server side issues that occur from time to time with GPGS. I'm guessing that for some reason the account was not properly authorized for Drive access (500 error is generic, so it's just a guess). You could try de-authorizing the app and try again perhaps.